# Loading a postgresql table into pandas dataframe with sqlalchemy hangs forever

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm trying to pull a table from a database into a pandas dataframe, but my code is hanging on the command to do so and I can't figure out why.

I've got:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas
import sqlalchemy
from pandas import DataFrame
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def connect():
    try:
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host/database')
        df = pandas.read_sql_table('mytable',engine,schema='mySchema')
        print("The dataframe loaded")
    except(Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

but when I run my code, it never makes it past the `df=` line. No errors or anything, just never prints and keeps running. I suspect this is some issue with the engine maybe not being set up properly?

Comment: Are you sure you have shared the complete code? I only see `try` block with no `except`

Comment: Also, your engine line needs the Postgres-python api: *psycopg2,
pg8000, psycopg2cffi, py-postgresql, pygresql* which also needs to be imported in script. Show import lines. See [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html).

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I have an except block and imports, I'll add those right now

Comment: @Parfait I've added psycopg2 and still have the same hanging happening in my function. Good spot though!

Comment: Curious, how big is your database? Hundreds of million-row, thousand-column tables? Can you check your code with a different database/schema?

Comment: it's not large, so that shouldn't be the reason for the hang.